# How to authenticate against a collection of domain objects in Spring Expression Language SpEL

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-el

My principle is an instance of 'foo' that has a collection of 'bars'. Each 'bar' has an id that I want to match with the 'id' passed as the resource requested.  Can I do something like the following in Spring SpEL?  And if so, how?

Example (psuedo syntax; cause I don't know the correct way which is why I am here)

```
@PreAuthorize("principal.transactions.contains(instance where dto.transactionId == instance.id")")
public SomeResponse processTransaction(RequestDto dto) {
    ...
}
```

Essentially the equivalent of this

```
for(Transaction t : principal.transactions){
    if(t.getId() == dto.getTransactionId())
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it is possible to do in plain SpEL. But you can try a workaround:

```
@PreAuthorize("principal.hasTransactionId(#dto.transactionId)")
```

Then you need to add **hasTransactionId(Integer transactionId)** method to your principal. This method must return a boolean value.

Comment: This solution worked to me. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15416652/1242531).