# Spring Security method rules: returned value contains a Collection

Tags: java, collections, spring-security, spring-el

In Spring Security I want to secure a method incorporating returned values and using `@PostAuthorize`.

I want to add a constraing that will not allow one user to access to resources they are not owners. The problem I face is that I want to check principal id against one collection of values.

Scenario:

Domain objects:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Collection<Driver> drivers;
    ...
}

public class Driver implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

Service:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or principal.id == returnObject.drivers.driver.id")
public Car getCar(int id) throws DAOException {
    ...        
    return carDAO.get(id);
}
```

Of course this Spel expression does not works.

```
SEVERE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [dispatcher] en el contexto con ruta [] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or principal.id == returnObject.drivers.driver.id'] con causa raíz
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 42): Field or property 'driver' cannot be found on object of type 'org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList'
```

I haven't seen any example that works over a Collection.
[This unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406090/how-to-authenticate-against-a-collection-of-domain-objects-in-spring-expression) is similar but I don't know if matches my particular scenario.
Is possible to do something like that?
It is another way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to rewrite your expression as follows:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or returnObject.hasDriverWithId(principal.id)")
```

and then add corresponding `hasDriverWithId` method to your Car class

Comment: Yes, it worked to me. This is the solution in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access the property `driver` on a List doesn't really make sense.  Are you wanting the first item in the list?  What about `returnObject.drivers[0].id`?

Comment: I want to check that principal is one of the drivers of the car. Let say car contains only the allowed drivers and if principal is not one of them, then it cannot access to this resource.